# android refresh/restart activity with updated variables

Tags: java, android, android-activity, refresh, updates

I'm making a quiz app and I'm looking to have my "practice questions" activity refresh itself with new questions with a previous/next button is pressed.  The questions are in an array placed inside a singleton "Global" class.

I want to update/refresh the activity so that a new question and set of answers pops up (ie. a counter is incremented/decremented when the previous/next button is pressed), but I don't want to reset the singleton class, which would re-randomize the questions in the array.  Intentionally, they're randomized every time the activity is accessed from the main screen.  I also have other variables (ie. counters, totals, flags) I would like to update with each passing to a new question.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

If it helps, the buttons are created and ID'd in XML And the Java file fills the buttons/textviews with strings.

Comment: on your button click do the changes,what is the problem you are facing

Comment: What's the problem exactly? Where are you facing the issue?

Comment: On another point, FYI there are tons of FLAG related application available on Google play store!

Comment: Well, I attempted to update the variables on the press of the previous/next buttons to show new questions.  I incremented/decremented the question array counter variable accordingly as well as some other useful variables, but I suppose I just don't know how to actually update the activity 1) to change the strings in the buttons/textviews using those variables, and 2) without recreating the instance of the "Global" singleton class (doing so would re-randomize the question array list).  I want the user to be able to use the next/previous buttons to move between the questions/answers...how?

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to update the text inside the views, then you don't need to refresh the `Activity`.  Instead, you can write an `updateViews()` method and call it when the previous/next button is pressed.

For example:

```
private void updateViews(String question, String answerA, String answerB,
                         String answerC, String answerD) {
    TextView tvQuestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
    TextView tvAnswerA = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer_a);
    TextView tvAnswerB = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer_b);
    TextView tvAnswerC = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer_c);
    TextView tvAnswerD = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer_d);

    tvQuestion.setText(question);
    tvAnswerA.setText(answerA);
    tvAnswerB.setText(answerB);
    tvAnswerC.setText(answerC);
    tvAnswerD.setText(answerD);
}
```

Obviously, you would need to tailor this approach to your views and data, as well as keep track of state (current question number, etc.), but this should give you an idea of one way to move ahead.